# how to make the table view to scroll till the last row in the table

Tags: objective-c

I have some 10 rows in my table. I can able to scroll the table view, but the scroll is not fixed. when i leave the scroll the table is again hiding the last row. Can any one help me out in this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the size of table view and also set the autosizing in inspector from IB.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give an opinion without any code, but have you checked that your Table is not larger that the size of the view? Maybe the bottom of your Table is just displayed outside the window.

If not, you shall post the code of your controller methods to get some more accurate help.

Are you using interface builder or everything is defined in the code?